# Launching and reloading Jetty from within IntelliJ IDEA (Scala, SBT)

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, jetty

I am sort of new to the Java world and I am developing a Scala app (using Scalatra and SBT) that runs on Jetty using IntelliJ IDEA. To get a faster workflow I would like to be able to launch Jetty from within the IDE and to be able to update the code without relaunching the Jetty server.

Currently I use the Jetty plugin for IntelliJ, which lets me launch the project on a Jetty server, but compiles the entire project and relaunches Jetty, which takes a lot of time. Is there a good way to do this faster? I already checked out JRebel (which is unfortunately too expensive at this point). Do I need JRebel/DCEVM or is this just a matter of configuring Jetty?

Answer (score 0):

Your application needs to be laid out so when it is compiled Jetty can directly read the artifacts and reload them. You could try this plugin to run jetty directly as part of sbt. https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin
Java will reload class files but there are rules on what can be reloaded like method bodies. Other wise you need JRebel or an alternative. Here is an IntelliJ blog that might help. http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/07/get-true-hot-swap-in-java-with-dcevm-and-intellij-idea/